# SFTP C# library with PuTTY private key (PPK) support

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, putty, private-key

I need a C# library that allows to send files to a SFTP server and that it accepts private keys in PuTTY format (PPK).

Does anyone know of such a library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) (C# wrapper around WinSCP scripting interface):

Its [`SessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#sshprivatekeypath) accepts a path to `.ppk` file.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Or you can use [PuTTYgen](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-puttygen) to convert the `.ppk` private key file to a format supported by your preferred SSH/SFTP library.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'm going to convert from openssh c# to winscp assembly too.